# Not able to see all markers at same position

Tags: html, css, angularjs, angular-google-maps

I am new in angular map.I getting issue when I have two markers at same coordinates.I am not able to click or see both markers.please help me.

Here is .js:-

```
this.map = {
      center: {
        latitude: -33.86,
        longitude: 151.2094
      },
      zoom: 7
    };

    this.markers = [{
      id: 0,
      latitude: -34,
      longitude: 151
    }, {
      id: 1,
      latitude: -34,
      longitude: 151
    }];

    this.f = f.bind(this); // Binding not needed if f uses g instead of this.g
    this.g = g;

    function f(marker, eventName, model, eventArgs) {
      $window.alert(
        'marker position: ' + marker.getPosition().toUrlValue() + '\n' +
        'event name: ' + eventName + '\n' +
        'model id: ' + model.id + '\n' +
        'mouse event position: ' + eventArgs[0].latLng.toUrlValue());
      this.g();
    }

    function g() {
      $window.alert('other method')
    }
```

Html:-

```
 <ui-gmap-google-map center="mc.map.center" zoom="mc.map.zoom">
    <ui-gmap-markers models="mc.markers" coords="'self'" click="mc.f">
    </ui-gmap-markers>
  </ui-gmap-google-map>
```

Here is plunker:-

https://plnkr.co/edit/luyIWAJBl5JtBxVfCPRO?p=preview

Comment: first thing you have to do is use: <ui-gmap-markers docluster="true" ...

Comment: docluster is depricated ..